# Creating and Accessing the Helper in the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-controller

I've created a helper file in `App` folder named as `Helper.php`.

**app/Helper.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Helper {

    public function get_username($user_id) 
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('userid', $user_id)->first();

        return (isset($user->username) ? $user->username : '');
    }
}
```

**app/Providers/HelperServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        require_once app_path() . 'Helper.php';
    }
}
```

*config/app.php*

Inside the provider's array...

```
App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class,
```

Inside `aliases` array...

```
'Helper' => App\Helper::class,
```

Everything was working fine but now I have the following error.

> ErrorException thrown with message "Non-static method Helper::get_username($user->id) should not be called statically

But when I add `static` keyword to function its works fine. What's the difference between static and non-static methods?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases give you the possibility to access a facade in a blade template without adding it in the template (vie use statement). When calling a method via a facade, you call this method statically and the facade will call the object of the class containing this method.

In Laravel, it is usually more convenient to create a file containing helpers like Laravel does and to autoload that file via composer.

[Please check here for more details](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers)